# Proving $(\frac{n}{p})$, a Legendre symbol, is multiplicative

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Proof:

if $p|n$ or $p|m$ then $p|nm$, so $(\frac{mn}{p})=0=(\frac{n}{p})(\frac{m}{p})$

If $p \nmid n$, then

$$(\frac{mn}{p}) \equiv (mn)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}(mod \text{ } p)$$
$$(\frac{mn}{p}) \equiv n^{\frac{p-1}{2}}m^{\frac{p-1}{2}}(mod \text{ } p)$$
$$(\frac{mn}{p}) \equiv (\frac{n}{p})(\frac{m}{p})(mod\text{ } p)$$
$$(\frac{mn}{p}) = 1\text{ } \textrm{or} \text{ } -1$$
$$(\frac{n}{p})(\frac{m}{p}) = 1\text{ } \textrm{or} \text{ } -1$$
$$(\frac{mn}{p}) \equiv (\frac{n}{p})(\frac{m}{p})(mod \text{ } p)$$
so $$(\frac{mn}{p})=(\frac{n}{p})(\frac{m}{p})$$

My question is how $$(\frac{mn}{p}) \equiv (\frac{n}{p})(\frac{m}{p}) \text{ }(mod\text{ } p)$$
becomes equality.

Answer (score 2):

The Legendre symbol is always $0$, $1$, or $-1$, by definition.  So you have a congruence mod $p$ where each side is actually just one of $0$, $1$, and $-1$ (and actually, in this case you know they can't be $0$).  Unless $p=2$, the only way two such numbers can be congruent mod $p$ is if they are actually equal.  You need to handle the case $p=2$ separately (but that case is rather trivial).